# Routing issues with react router, redux, browser history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, browser-history

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools'

import { Route, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

import App from './components/App'
import getRoutes from './routes'
import reducers from './reducers/index'

import * as storage from 'redux-storage'
import createEngine from 'redux-storage-engine-localstorage'


require('./stylesheets/main.scss');
const reducer = storage.reducer(reducers);

const engine = createEngine('my-save-key');

const storageMiddleware = storage.createMiddleware(engine, ['LOGOUT', '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE']);

const logger = createLogger({collapsed: true})
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, storageMiddleware, logger)(createStore)

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
const load = storage.createLoader(engine);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

console.log('loading store');
load(store)
.then( () => { 
  console.log('store is done loading') 
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Route path='/' component={App}>
            <Route path='profile/:username' component={User}/>
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
})
```

On my server, I have this to handle the requests:

```
  app.get('*', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile('index.html', {"root": "public"})
  })
```

Above is the main page to my app, where my react-router resides. I sync it up to the redux store. 
Here's the problem: I can navigate from the `App` to the `User` page. When I refresh the page, I expect to stay on the User page, but instead, I'm taken back to the App page. In fact, when I enter anything into the url, it always directs back to the App page. Why is this?

Comment: What do you have in the URL in browser after you have navigated to User page?

Comment: I figured out the problem: I was blacklisting the action dispatched by the router, and so the state was not saved after routing to another page. When I removed the the blacklist, it works as expected.